# Is it possible to start multiple applications with a single custom keyboard shortcut in "Keyboard" settings in Xubuntu?

Tags: bash, xubuntu, shortcut-keys

I have assigned `sh -c 'firefox & gnome-terminal & nautilus & google-chrome-stable & opera'` in "Keyboard" in Xubuntu 14.04 to open multiple applications *with a single shortcut*.

Whenever I trigger my keyboard shortcut, all of the programs open at the same time, which is what I was trying to do; **but, I am concerned that even though my solution works**, that using `&` instead of `;` to run a set of commands unconditionally could be a bad idea, or at the very least, improper. To elaborate, I actually did try `;` before I tried `&`, but it didn't work for some reason. `&&` also did not work for what I was trying to do, because it would open gnome-terminal only after I closed Firefox, and so on.

I barely know what I'm doing here, as I am inexperienced with shell stuff, so if someone more experienced could chip in and let me know whether or not my command is a good and viable solution for what I'm trying to do, it would be much appreciated.

[Image of Keyboard manager in Xubuntu 14.04, configured with the command I am presently using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvT0S.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Command lists and background invocation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Lists.html) is actually the right shell feature to do here. If the shell script works for you there are no considerable drawbacks in this context.